# Javascript search failures with indexOf

Tags: javascript, search, indexof

I have multiple elements (called cards), each with a dynamic amount of keywords. I want to search through them for matches on search input.

The problem - sometimes the function seems broken, if i wirte a "L" into the search input it just indicates the red card as a match, when i add a "U" it just shows the blue card. But the "L" should be a match on both cards and show them.

This failure is reproducible. There are various issues like this. Try to type in "Manager", if you just write the first letter no match will shown, on "Ma" the card is shown as a match.

What goes wrong on my function?

```js
document.getElementById('cardSearch').addEventListener('input', function(){
    var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
    var input = this.value.toUpperCase().replace(/ +(?= )/g,'').split(' ');
    var search = input.filter(Boolean);
    var noMatch = document.getElementById('noMatch');
    mismatchCount = 0;
    keywords = search.length;
    cardCycle = 0;

    searchCycle();

    //search cycle for every card
    function searchCycle() {
        var cycleMax = cards.length;
        cardMatch = 0;
        valueCycle = 0;

        searchValues();

        if(cardMatch == keywords) {
            cards[cardCycle].classList.remove('hidden');
        } else {
            cards[cardCycle].classList.add('hidden');
            mismatchCount++;
        }

        //check for mismatches - if all cards missmatched, show no matches text
        if(mismatchCount == cards.length) {
            noMatch.classList.remove('hidden');
        } else {
            noMatch.classList.add('hidden');
        }

        cardCycle++;

        if(cardCycle < cycleMax) {
            searchCycle();
        }
    }

    //search cycle for every input string, splitted by space
    function searchValues() {
        var metaData = cards[cardCycle].getAttribute('data-meta').toUpperCase().replace(/\s+/g, '').split(',');

        for(i = 0; i < metaData.length; i++) {
            if(metaData[i].indexOf(search[valueCycle]) > -1) {
                cardMatch++;
            }
        }

        valueCycle++;

        if(valueCycle < keywords) {
            searchValues();
        }
    }
})
```

```css
#cardSearch {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}

.card {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input id="cardSearch" type="text">
</header>

<span id="noMatch" class="hidden">no match</span>

<div class="card blue" data-meta="Manager, Lumpadau, public">
  <span>Manager, Lumpadau, public</span>
</div>

<div class="card red" data-meta="Worker, Reinde, public">
  <span>Worker, Reinde, public</span>
</div>

<div class="card green" data-meta="Cleaner, Rolls, private">
  <span>Cleaner, Rolls, private</span>
</div>
```

Comment: the code is now there, thanks @Sinto.

Comment: so if I search for "public" should i get both blue and red card? What if i search "public Lumpadau"

Comment: you should just get those cards with match with all search inputs. Jeah, on "public" you should get red and blue and on "public Lumpadau" just blue.

Comment: wow, you need to sort your variables out, can't tell which are globals, which are local or which are semi global (just to the event listener scope).  Just spent a good ten minutes having my mind blown

Comment: Your logic seems very convoluted. Why not just loop over the elements and test for a value match using *String.prototype.indexOf*, setting the *hidden* class based on the result? Maybe 4 or 5 lines of code.

Comment: @RobG - i took a deeper look and tryed to follow your assumption. The problem is, that if you have more then one search word, you need to verify which card matches all and not just one of these. Therefore my function is more complex and nested to do this.

Comment: @Flo—whatever, see my deleted answer for an example. May not be exactly what you want, but searching on words isn't much more complex that just character strings.

Comment: @RobG - how to see you deleted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i < metaData.length; i++) {
    if(metaData[i].indexOf(search[valueCycle]) > -1) {
        cardMatch++;
    }
}
```

In this part of code the cardMath is incremented not only on card but on every new matching symbol found. So, if only one symbol "L" is in the card it calculates correctly, but if there is more then one "L" - it sets value of cardMatch too high.

To resolve this, add break statement after finding first symbol in the card.

```
for(i = 0; i < metaData.length; i++) {
    if(metaData[i].indexOf(search[valueCycle]) > -1) {
        cardMatch++;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is updated jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kupdwj5q/14/